# Java code to get Frequency from FFT result

Tags: java, signal-processing, fft

I have an array of doubles containing audio samples coming directly from a microphone at a sampling rate of 44100. I want to get the fundamental frequency (the samples contain the amplitudes). On wikipedia in the autocorrelation page I found the description of the solution based on the Wiener-Khinchin theorem, I completed the algorithm with some more research over the internet and eventually I wrote the following code, but I am not sure whether it is correct:

```
private double determineFrequency(double[] signal) {
 //Get a FastFourierTransformer instance (Apache library)
 FastFourierTransformer fft = new FastFourierTransformer(DftNormalization.STANDARD);

 //The size of the array used by the fft must be a power of two, wrapping 
 //the original array in a bigger one padded to zero
 //NOTE: Here I assume that the input array is smaller than 8192
 double[] paddedSignal = new double[8192];
 System.arraycopy(signal, 0, paddedSignal, 0, signal.length);

 //First fft (forward) to switch from amplitude domain to the frequency domain
 Complex[] transformed = fft.transform(paddedSignal, TransformType.FORWARD);

 // Calculate the conjugate of the complex array
 for (int i=0; i<transformed.length; i++)
  transformed[i] = transformed[i].conjugate();

 //Second fft (inverse) to complete the autocorrelation
 transformed = fft.transform(transformed, TransformType.INVERSE);

 //Calculate the array of corresponding real values to switch 
 // from the frequency domain to the amplitude domain
 double[] autocorrelationMatrix = new double[transformed.length];
 for (int i=0; i<transformed.length; i++) {
  if (Double.isNaN(transformed[i].abs()) || Double.isInfinite(transformed[i].abs()))
   autocorrelationMatrix[i] = 0;
  else
   autocorrelationMatrix[i] = transformed[i].abs();
 }

 //Get the index of the max amplitude
 Integer indexOfMax = Utils.indexOfMax(autocorrelationMatrix);

 return transformed[indexOfMax].getReal()*audioFormat.getSampleRate()/transformed.length; 
}
```

Comment: Rather than the code I think there is still something to fix in the algorithm. When I try it it prints some funny numbers.

Comment: Nope, FFT is a well established algorithm.  It's your understanding and implementation that are wrong.

Comment: I didn't mean that there something wrong with the fft. I meant that probably there is something wrong with my algorithm.

Comment: It's pretty grim, but you should at least give some details about the inputs and outputs you've tried.

Comment: Why do you think the result is funny?

Answer (score 0):

You found the maximum value in the autocorrelation domain and then used that to read the frequency domain.  That will not work, any more than you can use an index in the time domain to learn something about the frequency domain.

Instead,

```
return autocorrelationMatrix[indexOfMax].getReal()*audioFormat.getSampleRate()/autocorrelationMatrix.length;
```

That said, you may find it easier to avoid the extra IFFT.  Instead, just extract the maximum absolute value from the frequency domain.  That will work to a resolution of sample rate / transform length, and can be refined with a little help from the phase of the maximum FFT bin.